# Status bar color is displaying at bottom of screen in xamarin forms iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, bottomnavigationview

In xamarin forms iOS, blue color is applying without providing any color at bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the [ios Safe Area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout)

If you have `Page.SafeArea=True` with a device with rounded corner, it will "truncate" a part. And show the `Page.BackgroundColor` behind (blue in your case)

If it's false, it will not truncate, but the content might be shown in an undesired way because of the rounded borders

I show you a Page with `BackgroundColor="Red"` and a `StackLayout` with `BackgroundColor="Yellow"`

On the right the page has `Page.SafeArea="True"` and on the left, with a `False` value

[image]